# Databricks Flatten Nested JSON to Dataframe with PySpark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am trying to Convert a nested JSON to a flattened DataFrame.

I have read in the JSON as follows:

```
df = spark.read.json("/mnt/ins/duedil/combined.json")
```

The resulting dataframe looks like the following:

[image]

I have made a start on flattening the dataframe as follows

```
display(df.select ("companyId","countryCode"))
```

The above will display the following

[image]

I would like to select 'fiveYearCAGR" under the following: "financials:element:amortisationOfIntangibles:fiveYearCAGR"

Can someone let me know how to add to the select statement to retrieve the fiveYearCAGR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `financials` is an array so if you want to extract something within the `financials`, you need some array transformations.

One example is to use `transform`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.select(
    "companyId",
    "countryCode",
    F.transform('financials', lambda x: x['amortisationOfIntangibles']['fiveYearCAGR']).alias('fiveYearCAGR')
)
```

This will return the `fiveYearCAGR` in an array. If you need to flatten it further, you can use `explode`/`explode_outer`.

Comment: Hi emma, thanks for reaching out. I'm getting the error that F is not defined. Should that be a function?

Comment: Yes it is the pyspark's functions. I added the import line.

Comment: Thank you Emma. You're a star